# Cumulative sequence of occurrences of values

Tags: r, sequence

I have a dataset that looks something like this, with a column that can have four different values:

```
dataset <- data.frame(out = c("a","b","c","a","d","b","c","a","d","b","c","a"))
```

In R, I'd like to create a second column that tallies, in sequence, the cumulative number of rows containing a particular value. Thus the output column would look like this:

```
out
1
1
1
2
1
2
2
3
2
3
3
4
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataset <- data.frame(out = c("a","b","c","a","d","b","c","a","d","b","c","a"))
with(dataset, ave(as.character(out), out, FUN = seq_along))
# [1] "1" "1" "1" "2" "1" "2" "2" "3" "2" "3" "3" "4"
```

Of course, you can assign the output to a column in your `data.frame` using something like `out$asNumbers <- with(dataset, ave(as.character(out), out, FUN = seq_along))`

#### Update

The "dplyr" approach is also quite nice. The logic is very similar to the "data.table" approach. An advantage is that you don't need to wrap the output with `as.numeric` which would be required with the `ave` approach mentioned above.

```
dataset %>% group_by(out) %>% mutate(count = sequence(n()))
# Source: local data frame [12 x 2]
# Groups: out
# 
#    out count
# 1    a     1
# 2    b     1
# 3    c     1
# 4    a     2
# 5    d     1
# 6    b     2
# 7    c     2
# 8    a     3
# 9    d     2
# 10   b     3
# 11   c     3
# 12   a     4
```

---

A third option is to use `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package. For this particular example, you just need to specify the `data.frame` name (since it's a single column), however, generally, you would be more specific and mention the column(s) that presently serve as "ids", and the function would check whether they are unique or whether a cumulative sequence is required to make them unique.

```
library(splitstackshape)
# getanID(dataset, "out")  ## Example of being specific about column to use
getanID(dataset)
#     out .id
#  1:   a   1
#  2:   b   1
#  3:   c   1
#  4:   a   2
#  5:   d   1
#  6:   b   2
#  7:   c   2
#  8:   a   3
#  9:   d   2
# 10:   b   3
# 11:   c   3
# 12:   a   4
```

Comment: My thought as well. A question: don't you reckon the documentation for argument `x` in `?ave` is misleading? (It indicates `x` should be numeric, but "character" class vectors obviously work too.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, true... And the name of the function... and the first line in the documentation... All misleading! I think I only learned about this feature from observing a few answers here on SO (a lot from DWin).

Comment: What's the best way to notify R-core about little details like this, I wonder?  Is the R-devel mailing list the recommended channel? Or is a documentation error like this too small for them to care about?

Comment: `%.%` was not recognized function. `%>%` worked for me.

Comment: @urwaCFC, note the date of the original answer. Back then, the "dplyr" package, which is still in rapid function-breaking development mode, used `%.%` instead of `%>%`.

Answer (score 7):

### Update:

As Ananda pointed out, you can use the simpler:

```
 DT[, counts := sequence(.N), by = "V1"]
```

(where `DT` is as below)

---

You can create a "counts" column, initialized to 1, then tally the cumulative sum, by factor.
below is a quick implementation with `data.table`

```
# Called the column V1
dataset<-data.frame(V1=c("a","b","c","a","d","b","c","a","d","b","c","a"))

library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(dataset)

DT[, counts := 1L]
DT[, counts := cumsum(counts), by=V1]; DT

#     V1 counts
#  1:  a      1
#  2:  b      1
#  3:  c      1
#  4:  a      2
#  5:  d      1
#  6:  b      2
#  7:  c      2
#  8:  a      3
#  9:  d      2
# 10:  b      3
# 11:  c      3
# 12:  a      4
```

Comment: A more direct approach would be: `DT[, counts := sequence(.N), by = "V1"]` ... but I'm not sure what was available in `data.table` at the time of this answer! :)

Comment: haha, yes, absolutely.   This answer is from 7 months ago, ;)   but I'm sure .N was already available, I just overlooked it.  Ive gone ahead and edited