# How to sequentially number a vector in R based on changing unique values?

Tags: r, vector, unique, sequence, apply

Assume I have the following vector:

```
dat <- c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3, 4,4,4,4)   <- (I added spaces to better see grouping)
```

I would like to assign sequential numbers starting with `1` restarting for each unique value in `dat`. The desired result would be:

```
1 2 3   1 2 3   1 2   1 2 3 4    <- (I added spaces to better see grouping)
```

---

My attempt:

```
unlist(
  lapply(unique(dat), function(x) 
     seq(1,length(which(dat==x)==T),1)
  )
)

[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 1 2 3 4
```

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Comment: If there is only one run per value: [Numbering rows within groups in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame), else [R: count consecutive occurrences of values in a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998836/r-count-consecutive-occurrences-of-values-in-a-single-column)

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
sequence(rle(dat)$lengths)
```

Comment: Wonderful! That moves much quicker on my data set of 180k rows :). Thanks!

Comment: Also, I never knew about `rle()` -- what a great function!