# Count and Assign Consecutive Occurrences of Variable

Tags: r, count, find-occurrences

I wish to count consecutive occurrence of any value and assign that count to that value in next column. Below is the example of input and desired output:

```
dataset <- data.frame(input = c("a","b","b","a","a","c","a","a","a","a","b","c"))
dataset$count <- c(1,2,2,2,2,1,4,4,4,4,1,1)

dataset  
   input   count
     a       1
     b       2
     b       2
     a       2
     a       2
     c       1
     a       4
     a       4
     a       4
     a       4
     b       1
     c       1
```

With `rle(dataset$input)` I can just get number of occurrences of each value. But I want resulting output in above format.

My question is similar to:
 [R: count consecutive occurrences of values in a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998836/r-count-consecutive-occurrences-of-values-in-a-single-column)
But here output is in sequence and I want to assign the count itself to that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can repeat the `lengths` argument `lengths` time in `rle`

```
with(rle(dataset$input), rep(lengths, lengths))
#[1] 1 2 2 2 2 1 4 4 4 4 1 1
```

---

Using `dplyr`, we can use `lag` to create groups and then count the number of rows in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
  group_by(gr = cumsum(input != lag(input, default = first(input)))) %>%
  mutate(count = n())
```

and with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataset)[, count:= .N, rleid(input)]
```

**data**

Make sure the `input` column is character and not `factor`.

```
dataset <- data.frame(input = c("a","b","b","a","a","c","a","a","a","a","b","c"),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rleid` with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>%
   group_by(grp = rleid(input)) %>%
   mutate(count = n())
```