# Assigning the position of positive and negative values in sequence

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = tibble(
        quarter = c(seq.Date(as.Date("2022-03-01"), as.Date("2023-12-01"), "quarter")),
        value = c(rnorm(3), 0, rnorm(4))
     )
    
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  quarter       value
  <date>        <dbl>
1 2022-03-01 -0.670  
2 2022-06-01 -0.00760
3 2022-09-01  1.78   
4 2022-12-01  0      
5 2023-03-01 -1.14   
6 2023-06-01  1.37   
7 2023-09-01  1.33   
8 2023-12-01  0.336
```

I want to find the position of each positive and negative value that is in a sequence that starts and ends when the sign of values changes; for the special case of a `0`, it should be assign 'zero'. So my final desired output would be something like:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  quarter       value position    
  <date>        <dbl> <chr>       
1 2022-03-01 -0.670   1st negative
2 2022-06-01 -0.00760 2nd negative
3 2022-09-01  1.78    1st positive
4 2022-12-01  0       zero        
5 2023-03-01 -1.14    1st negative
6 2023-06-01  1.37    1st positive
7 2023-09-01  1.33    2nd positive
8 2023-12-01  0.336   3nd positive
```

After racking my brain I think that I found a solution that is not so elegant:

```
 df %>% 
   mutate(position = coalesce(accumulate(ifelse(sign(value) - lag(sign(value)) != 0 | row_number() == 1, 1, NA),
                                         ~ ifelse(is.na(.y), .x + 1, .y))),
          position = ifelse(sign(value) > 0, paste(position, "pos"), 
                            ifelse(sign(value) < 0, paste(position, "neg"), 'zero')))

# A tibble: 8 × 3
  quarter       value position
  <date>        <dbl> <chr>   
1 2022-03-01 -0.670   1 neg   
2 2022-06-01 -0.00760 2 neg   
3 2022-09-01  1.78    1 pos   
4 2022-12-01  0       zero    
5 2023-03-01 -1.14    1 neg   
6 2023-06-01  1.37    1 pos   
7 2023-09-01  1.33    2 pos   
8 2023-12-01  0.336   3 pos
```

My question: **is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more concise way:

First we identify all changes +/- in x, then group by x and assign row numbers and finally paste all together in a `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(x = cumsum(c(1, diff(sign(value)) != 0))) %>% 
  mutate(y = row_number(), 
         position = case_when(
    value > 0 ~ paste(y, "positive"),
    value < 0 ~ paste(y, "negative"),
    .default = 'zero'), .by=x) %>% 
  select(-c(x,y))

 quarter     value position  
  <date>      <dbl> <chr>     
1 2022-03-01 -0.556 1 negative
2 2022-06-01  1.79  1 positive
3 2022-09-01  0.498 2 positive
4 2022-12-01  0     zero      
5 2023-03-01 -1.97  1 negative
6 2023-06-01  0.701 1 positive
7 2023-09-01 -0.473 1 negative
8 2023-12-01 -1.07  2 negative
```

Answer (score 2):

As a base R option, you could use a modified [`sequence(rle(...))`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19998876/12109788) approach on the `sign(df$value)` to count the runs of consecutive signs, then `ifelse` to create the `position` variable:

```
x <- sequence(rle(sign(df$value))$lengths)
# [1] 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2

df$position <- ifelse(df$value < 0, paste0(x[df$value < 0], " negative"),
                      ifelse(df$value > 0, paste0(x[df$value > 0], " positive"),
                             "zero"))
```

Output

```
#   quarter     value position      
#   <date>      <dbl> <chr>     
# 1 2022-03-01 -0.481 1 negative
# 2 2022-06-01  1.10  1 positive
# 3 2022-09-01 -0.254 1 negative
# 4 2022-12-01  0     zero      
# 5 2023-03-01  1.76  1 positive
# 6 2023-06-01 -0.203 1 negative
# 7 2023-09-01 -1.26  1 negative
# 8 2023-12-01  0.180 1 positive
```